# AlwaysOn Availability Group Listener access

Tags: sql, listener, alwayson

This question is about the *correct* way of accessing an Availability Group Listener?

Assume I have two AlwaysOn Availability Groups with the following AG's: `AG1` and `AG2`.
I also have 2 listeners called `LISTENER1` (on AG1) and `LISTENER2` (on AG2).
I have 2 SQL nodes `NODE1` and `NODE2` and both have 2 SQL instances running: `INSTANCE1` and `INSTANCE2`.

How do I *correctly* connect to the primary replica of `AG1` via the listener?
I know it's not supposed to be NODE1\INSTANCE, but which of the following is correct?

```
LISTENER1
```

or

```
LISTENER1\INSTANCE1
```

I noticed both work fine and I assume the latter connects to the primary replica of LISTENER1 and than lets SQL Browser do its magic and connects to INSTANCE1 (which - by luck - happens to be correct in this particular setup).

I noticed if I use LISTENER1\INSTANCE2, this works as well, BUT connects to the INSTANCE2 instance of the node which hosts the primary replica of AG1!

The rabbit hole goes even futher: if I install a default instance on both SQL nodes I get yet another behavior: Connecting to `LISTENER1`, connects me to the default instance.

Is my logic correct (SQL Browser service) or am I just completely wrong here?

FYI: Named instances in this case use dynamic ports and all listeners are hosted on port 1433

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `LISTENER1\INSTANCE1` 
because you have two instances and those are not default instance